# How do I use the OpenCL C++/C++ for OpenCL kernel languages?

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I have only tried compiling kernels using pyopencl, but I can only seem to be able to use OpenCl C. Looking at clinfo, I only see support for CLC listed, heres some truncated output from my pc:

```
  Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor                                 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.1 AMD-APP (3423.0)
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback
  Platform Extensions function suffix             AMD
  Platform Host timer resolution                  1ns

  Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     gfx1031
  Device Vendor                                   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Device Vendor ID                                0x1002
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 2.0
  Driver Version                                  3423.0 (HSA1.1,LC)
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 2.0
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Board Name (AMD)                         AMD Radeon RX 6700 XT
  Device PCI-e ID (AMD)                           0x73df
  Device Topology (AMD)                           PCI-E, 0000:2f:00.0
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Max compute units                               20
```

I am using a rocm driver compiled from the AUR, I tried to also install the mesa driver alongside but could not do so (perhaps I need to uninstall the other, but I dread having to recompile it if mesa fails).

My laptop (intel hd graphics) seems to support OpenCL 3.0 but also only lists CLC support. What am I missing, is this not implemented yet? I saw something somewhere about "offline compilation" and maybe using a "clc++" option with clang but can someone elaborate?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ for OpenCL can be used in two ways:

###### Online compilation

If OpenCL device supports [`cl_ext_cxx_for_opencl`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/extensions/ext/cl_ext_cxx_for_opencl.html), it is possible to compile a program written using the C++ for OpenCL kernel language in runtime. Applications may pass `-cl-std=CLC++` to `clCompileProgram` and `clBuildProgram` for programs created using `clCreateProgramFromSource` to request the program be built as C++ for OpenCL.

###### Offline compilation

If OpenCL device allows to create the program with SPIR-V, then it is possible to compile C++ for OpenCL source into intermediate LLVM IR:

```
clang -c -cl-std=clc++ -target spir64 -O3 -emit-llvm -o test.ll test.clcpp
```

Next, LLVM IR can be translated into SPIR-V using [`llvm-spirv`](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-LLVM-Translator):

```
llvm-spirv test.ll -o test.spv
```

Finally, OpenCL program can be created using `clCreateProgramWithIL` call:

```cpp
std::ifstream il_file("test.spv", std::ios::binary);
std::vector<char> il_buffer;
std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(il_file),
          std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
          std::back_inserter(il_buffer));

cl_program program = 
    clCreateProgramWithIL(context, il_buffer.data(), il_buffer.size(), &ret);
```

For PyOpenCL:

```py
with open('test.spv', 'rb') as il_file:
    il_buffer = bytes(il_file.read())

prg = cl.Program(ctx, il_buffer)
```

To check that OpenCL device supports SPIR-V modules, you need to use `CL_DEVICE_IL_VERSION` query in OpenCL 2.1 or newer and the `CL_DEVICE_ILS_WITH_VERSION` query in OpenCL 3.0 or newer.

For additional information about offline compilation please see [Offline Compilation of OpenCL Kernels into SPIR-V Using Open Source Tooling](https://www.khronos.org/blog/offline-compilation-of-opencl-kernels-into-spir-v-using-open-source-tooling) article.

Comment: Many thanks! Sadly I cannot seem to be able to find mention of either of those in my clinfo. Wikipedia mentions "the specification deprecates the OpenCL C++ Kernel Language, replacing it with the C++ for OpenCL language" (in OCL version 3.0), was the older language accessed the same way/does it need the same extensions? And one more silly question in desperation: device definitely refers to the hardware (my GPU in this case) and not just the driver or something? (i.e. definitely no support for my current hardware?)

Comment: The online compilation for C++ for OpenCL language is supported only in OpenCL 3.0 if OpenCL device has `cl_ext_cxx_for_opencl` extension. According to the [specification](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_API.html#clCreateProgramWithSource), OpenCL 2.2 and older versions does not support the online compilation for OpenCL C++ language at all. Formally, the term "OpenCL device" in the answer refers to the device object that is returned by `clGetDeviceIDs` function. But usually, the OpenCL devices maps one-to-one to the hardware devices.