# Loading clang-compiled OpenCL kernels into OpenCL programs

Tags: c++, ubuntu, clang, opencl

Using clang, I am able to compile OpenCL-C++ kernels (using `clang -c`). I am trying to load these compiled kernels into my OpenCL application, but am at a loss how to achieve that. I am using Ubuntu 22.04, with an Intel CPU and an Nvidia GPU. The GPU unfortunately does not support SPIR-V injection via `clCreateProgramWithIL` - if it did, I would happily take that route. I also cannot use `clCreateProgamWithSource`, because that unfortunately does not support C++ features inside the kernels.

Is there any way I can compile OpenCL-C++ kernels using `clang` and then load them into my OpenCL application? Or is there a way I can still use `clCreateProgramWithSource` with C++ features inside the kernels, maybe? Either way would work well! (There has been a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938591/opencl-load-program-from-binary) but focusing on macOS, which has its own OpenCL implementation and compiler, as far as I know.)

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73179473/how-do-i-use-the-opencl-c-c-for-opencl-kernel-languages/73198633#73198633 ?

Comment: Yes, that does help, thank you so much! I have yet to encounter a device that actually supports `cl_ext_cxx_for_opencl` but in the meantime I was able to go the SPIR-V route and managed to load C++ OpenCL kernels into my application going that little detour.

Comment: @mikulcak Can you share how you managed to get spirv to run on nvidia gpu, please?

Comment: That's not possible, unfortunately. The Nvidia implementation of the OpenCL standard does not support that particular extension. I ended up running the SPIR-V kernels on the integrated graphics on my Intel CPU.